# How to access content of mapping in a struct?

Tags: solidity, mapping, struct

I'm aware of this post:

[Accessing a mapping within a struct via Truffle console](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/25544/accessing-a-mapping-within-a-struct-via-truffle-console)

However, it seems to me, it does not provide a clear answer. Also, my question is more generic and not just for truffle. Also, there's similar code in [here](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.3/types.html) (section "structs") but couldn't find any answer to the below questions.

---

Case 1:

Assume we have the following pseudo-code in solidity:

```
mapping (uint => BB) public map_1; 

struct BB{

  mapping (uint => address) map_2;
}
```

**Question** : Given a key, how can I access the content of map_2 in Geth or a user interface?

---

Case 2:

Assume we have the following pseudo-code in solidity:

```
mapping (uint => BB) public map_1; 

struct AA{
uint val;
}

struct BB{

  mapping (uint => AA) map_2;
}
```

My question for this case remains the same as the one for case 1.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the case 1s mapping by given the both keys. The key for `map_1` and key for `map_2`. Use `pragma solidity ^0.4.20;` when compiling

**Case 1**

```
contract test {
    struct BB {
        mapping(uint => string) map_2;
    }
    mapping(uint => BB) map_1;

    function test() public {
        map_1[1].map_2[1] = "hello"; //setting temp value
    }

    function maping() public view returns(string) {
        return map_1[1].map_2[1]; //accessing the value
    }
}
```

**Case 2**

```
contract test {
    struct BB {
        mapping(uint => AA) map_2;
    }
    struct AA{
        uint val;
    }
    mapping(uint => BB) map_1;

    function test() public {
        map_1[1].map_2[1].val = 10;
    }

    function maping() public view returns(uint) {
        return map_1[1].map_2[1].val;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Case 1**

You cannot make `map_1` `public` because the compiler doesn't know how to construct the "free" getter than comes with `public`. You have to make it yourself, like this:

```
pragma solidity 0.5.1;

contract Case1 {

    struct BB{
        mapping (uint => address) map_2;
    }

    mapping (uint => BB) map_1; 

    function getter(uint structId, uint mapId) public view returns(address) {
        return map_1[structId].map_2[mapId];
    }  
}
```

That means you have a function that accepts two `uint` arguments and returns an address at the requested coordinates.

**Case 2**

Same as above.

```
contract Case2 {

    struct AA{
        uint val;
    }

    struct BB{

        mapping (uint => AA) map_2;
    }

    mapping (uint => BB) map_1; 

    function getter(uint BBId, uint AAId) public view returns(uint val) {
        return map_1[BBId].map_2[AAId].val;
    }
}
```

In this case `val` in the `returns` phrase is merely an optional label for the `uint` that will be returned.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer Rob!